# owl carousel random order

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to randomize the order of slides during autoplay in an owl carousel.  I referenced this (http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/randomOrder.html) on their site but all that does is reset the order on load (beforeInit).  I tried playing around with the other callbacks but no luck.  Anyone out there have a solution?  Here's an example of what I thought would work.  Apparently, I'm missing the point of the callbacks:

```
function random(owlSelector){
owlSelector.children().sort(function(){
    return Math.round(Math.random()) - 0.5;
}).each(function(){
  $(this).appendTo(owlSelector);
});
}

$(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({

beforeMove : function(elem){

  random(elem);
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved (sort of).  I ended up using the wow slider. It has an option to make the slide sequence random.